# Auto-creating tables with "update-database.." from Model does not work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am new in ASP.NET MVC programming and i have followed the tutorial ["Entity Framework 6" from Pluralsight](http://pluralsight.com/training/Player?author=scott-allen&name=aspdotnet-mvc5-fundamentals-m6-ef6&mode=live&clip=0&course=aspdotnet-mvc5-fundamentals).

I am currently stuck at the "Multiple Migration" section. He says that the command

```
update-database -ConfigurationTypeName Books.Web.DataContexts.IdentityMigrations.Configuration
```

in the package-manager-console will automatically create tables in the Server Explorer. But it does not work. I get the an Error like this:

> Network related or instance -specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server . The server was not found , or can not access it . Check if the instance name is correct and that SQL Server allows remote connections. Error: 50 - Error in the Local Database Runtime. The specified LocalDB instance does not exist.

I have read other questions with the similar problem but I was not able to fix it.

Comment: Could you post your connection strings from your web.config file?

Comment: sure,
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Movies.Web-20151220063141.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Movies.Web-20151220063141;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: Gotcha...well I'm sure he goes through setting up contexts and what not if he's teaching Entity...so I would just go back through and double check that your DataContexts are all setup appropriately and that DefaultConnection is correct based on your available servers, dbs, etc...

Comment: I have done exactly the same. Enabling and adding migrations works fine but as already mentioned when it comes to the "update-database.." command i get the error. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really sounds like either A) You don't have a DB server running or you aren't connected to the server or B) Your connection string in your web.config is wrong.

Comment: A) According to the tutorial i dont have to set up a DB server. Visual Studio does have the Server Data Tool which will do that automatically.

B) I did not change anything, the tutor also did not change anything